# keep getting seg fault in sorting name using malloc

Tags: sorting, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm suppose to read a file and then write to the file in an alphabatically sorted array. However, I am keep getting a segmentation fault using gdb, indicating my display and sort function occur segmentation fault.

EDIT: I fixed it by use a macro to allocate memory.
Since it is an assignment, I do not wish to disclose it just in case. I do appreciate everyone's help on my code.

Comment: Could you maybe be a bit more generous w/ the comments?  And while you're at it, the indentation?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a core dump of your binary compiled with symbols?

Comment: Add the output of running bt in gdb to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to do this? Ouch.

I got a segfault too, but in read_names(). I was able to fix it by replacing all the strtok() stuff with a simple scanf():

```
    void read_names (FILE *fp, char **f, char **l, char *m, int num)//read it
    {
        int i=0;
        char temp[80];

        for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        { 
            fscanf( fp, "%s %s %s", f[i], l[i], m);
        }
    }
```

After that I was able to sort & print, though it's trying to free() something erroneously at the end.

I general strtok() is insecure and just a pain - it destroys your string.

Also, more meaningful names make it easier to work with. I eventually figured out that "l[]" was an array of strings containing the last name, but something along the lines of "sLastName[]" would have sped that up immensely.

EDIT:

I gathered your input text file looked like this:

```
2 bill smith a doug adams r
```

EDIT2:

OK, found another segfault.  What is "num"? It seems to be interpreted as kindof the number of names in the file and kindof the size of each name?

```
// allocate "num" first name elements -> implied "num" is # of names
f=(char**)malloc (num*sizeof(char*));

// allocate space for each name... but uses the value of "num" for each name
for (i=0; i<num;i++)
    f[i]=(char*)malloc (num*sizeof(char));  // "num" bytes per name?
```

When I started allocating 100 bytes per name instead of the value of "num", the second - and for me last - segfault went away.

Did you enter the entire program and then start testing? It would be a lot easier to get it working in small steps then incrementally adding functionality - verifying with debugger and/or printf() that it's doing what you want at each step.

Comment: I fixed it. instead of using num, I suppose to use a macro for those ones inside the loop. Thanks everyone for the input. I appreciate it.